# Use of nullable types and null-coalescing operator together in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, null-coalescing-operator

In the following MSDN Official article on [LINQ Outer Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins), author(s) are using [?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/index) and [??](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) together in `...select new { person.FirstName, PetName = subpet?.Name ?? String.Empty };`. **Question**: Why not just use `??` as: `select new { person.FirstName, PetName = subpet.Name ?? String.Empty };` that, I think, translates to `if subpet.Name is null give me empty string`. Am I misunderstanding something?

**Reason for the Inquiry**: When I was using `?` and `??` together in my code (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44681362/1232087)) the `VS2015` Intellisense was giving me the error also explained in that post.

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
}

public static void LeftOuterJoinExample()
{
    Person magnus = new Person { FirstName = "Magnus", LastName = "Hedlund" };
    Person terry = new Person { FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams" };
    Person charlotte = new Person { FirstName = "Charlotte", LastName = "Weiss" };
    Person arlene = new Person { FirstName = "Arlene", LastName = "Huff" };

    Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
    Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
    Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
    Pet bluemoon = new Pet { Name = "Blue Moon", Owner = terry };
    Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };

    // Create two lists.
    List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
    List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy };

    var query = from person in people
                join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { person.FirstName, PetName = subpet?.Name ?? String.Empty };

    foreach (var v in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{v.FirstName+":",-15}{v.PetName}");
    }
}

// This code produces the following output:
//
// Magnus:        Daisy
// Terry:         Barley
// Terry:         Boots
// Terry:         Blue Moon
// Charlotte:     Whiskers
// Arlene:
```

Comment: `subpet.Name` will throw if `subpet` is null.

Comment: `subpet?.Name ?? String.Empty` will evaluate to an empty string regardless if `subpet` is null or `subpet.Name` is null

Comment: @SirRufo My confusion was due to an error I was getting in one of my code as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44681362/1232087). But I think `@JonSkeet` and `@hvd` have explained it at that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Lee, `subpet` might be null. So, in calling `subpet.Name` throw an exception.Hence, `??` check the `subpet` is null or not, and `?` back to the calling `.Name` property.

Comment: Thanks. Also, please see my comments above for the reason of my question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not misunderstanding. The programmer was testing `subpet` for null, because of [DefaultIfEmpty()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179(v=vs.110).aspx)

In the expression

```
    subpet?.Name ?? String.Empty
```

- `subpet` can be null, in which case `subpet?.Name` is also null.
- `String.Empty` can be shortened to ""

So to ensure a non-null string,

```
    subpet?.Name ?? ""
```

Comment: So... The OP *is* misunderstanding?

Comment: @buffjape. Thank you for explaining. But I did indeed misunderstand the proper uses of ? and ??. Please see my other SO question here that prompted me to post the above question.

Comment: ok no problem. It seemed to me you were asking "Why use the `?.` operator here", instead of "What does the operator do?".