# Update linq query results

Tags: c#, linq

The following code has a join on the `Users` table (wrong) that gives me only the records where `AssignedUserId` is not `null`. I need all of the records in `Request` regardless of the `AssignerUserId`, and then add the `User.Name` when the `AssignedUserId` is not `null`.

```
var query = from r in _context.Request
    join st in _context.ServiceType on r.ServiceTypeId equals st.ServiceTypeId
    join u in _context.Users on r.UserId equals u.UserId
    select new RequestDto
    {
        RequestId = r.RequestId,
        UserId = r.UserId,
        FirstName = r.FirstName,
        //...
        ServiceType = st.ServiceName,
        AssignedUserId = r.AssignedUserId,
        AssignedUser = u.Name
    };

return query.ToList();
```

How do I get the `User.Name` for only the records where the `AssignedUserId` is not `null`?

Comment: Question is unclear... what do you mean *Users table (wrong)*? What is `r.AssignedUserId` compared to `r.UserId`?

Comment: Is there a mistake here "on r.UserId equals u.UserId" ? . Maybe It would be "on r.AssignedUserId equals u.UserId" ?

Comment: by (wrong) I meant that this query is only returning the records where AssignedUserId is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a left join - to retrieve the data from the requested but to join the `Users` table only when possible:

```
var query = from r in _context.Request
    join st in _context.ServiceType on r.ServiceTypeId equals st.ServiceTypeId
    join u in _context.Users on r.AssignedUserId equals u.UserId into ju
    from u in ju.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new RequestDto
    {
        // ....
        AssignedUserId = r.AssignedUserId,
        AssignedUser = u?.Name
    };
```

As for your exception from the comments see [an expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44681362/6400526).

Replace `u.Name` with `u == null ? null : u.Name`

Comment: I'm not sure what the ? in u?.Name does....  When I try this solution I get an error, "An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator."  When I take out the ? I'm still just getting the records that contain an AssignedUserId.

Comment: Also, in reviewing the results set, my AssignedUserId is actually equal to 0. It is not null.  There is no UserId = 0.  How do I use this left join and lookup Users only when AssignedUserId > 0?

Comment: Same query... how can I also put the datediff of AssignedDate and DateTime.Now into AssignedElapsed?  ie; AssignedElapsed = DateDiff(r.AssignedDate.Value, DateTime.Now)

Comment: @P-Finny - it is a followup question and unfortunately I should not be answering it here.. Please search online for similar questions or references and if you can't solve it then you can post a new question

Answer (score 0):

You want to perform `left join`

```
        var query = from r in _context.Request
            join st in _context.ServiceType on r.ServiceTypeId equals st.ServiceTypeId
            join u in _context.Users on r.AssignedUserId equals u.UserId into ps
            from u in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new RequestDto
            {
                RequestId = r.RequestId,
                UserId = r.UserId,
                FirstName = r.FirstName,
                ServiceType = st.ServiceName,
                AssignedUserId = r.AssignedUserId,
                AssignedUser = u?.Name
            };
```

I am assuming that join with `Users` condition is `"r.AssignedUserId`". Also, It could be better to use navigation properties instead of manual joins.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
AssignedUser = r.AssignedUserId == null ? null : u.Name
```

If you don't want `AssignedUser` to be `null` you can set it to `String.Empty` instead.

Comment: You can simplify it to `AssignedUser = r.AssignedUserId ?? u.Name`

Comment: @FCin: What you are suggesting is not the same thing. What you wrote reads: If r.AssignedUserId is null use u.Name otherwise use r.AssignedUserId. Not what the user is asking. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c