# How to null check @Html.DisplayNameFor with IEnumerable - C# & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure if I'm searching this incorrectly, but I can't seem to determine as to how to `null` check `@Html.DisplayNameFor`.

I have an `IEnumerable<model>` which has a `model.Numbers` `model.Order` and `model.Time`:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Numbers)
```

etc.

I tried doing a this but VS throws an error on:

> ```
> @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model?.Numbers)
> ```

But I get this message when I hover over the red squiggly in VS:

> An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator

I've also tried appending `where()` and `@Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Numbers.Any())` but these do not work.

My code:

```html
@model IEnumerable<BusinessLayer.NumbersModel>

...

<table class="table table-sm">

    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Numbers)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Order)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Time)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.Numbers != null && item.Order != null && item.Time != null)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Numbers)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Order)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Time)</td>
                <td><i class="m-icon--edit"></i> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "m-numbers__link" })</td>
                <td>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Numbers", new { id = item.ID }))
                    {
                        <i class="m-icon--delete"></i> <input type="submit" value="Bin" onclick="return confirm('You are about to delete this record');" />
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Model:

```cs
public class NumbersModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Numbers { get; set; }
    public string Order { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: `An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.` is what I get when I hover over the red squiggly line in VS with the `?`

Comment: You may want to read the accepted answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681362/an-expression-tree-lambda-may-not-contain-a-null-propagating-operator)

Comment: If your `@model` is `IEnumerable<model>`, then surely you can't call `.Numbers` etc on that. You probably have a loop on the page that enumerates the `Model`, and it's the loop variable that you pass to the lambda.

Comment: I have a loop after I call `DisplayNameFor` three times that iterates through the models and renders the data via `DisplayFor`

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Can you show that part of the view, including the `@model` clause?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my question now.

Comment: I'm still not sure, but it would appear you want something like `DisplayNameFor(m => m.First().Numbers)`.

Comment: what is the type of Model.Numbers?

Comment: 1) Please explain what is your expectation from this code: `DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Numbers)` 2) Please show us the class for your Model.

Comment: I'll edit my question again - they are all strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@model` is an [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8). It does not have `.Numbers` or `.Order`, the objects it contains do.

`DisplayNameFor()` only needs to know the type of the expression to get the attribute `DisplayAttribute` from. The expression you pass to it does not have to calculate to a non-null instance of the object, it will not be executed for its result.

So

```html
<thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.First().Numbers)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.First().Order)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.First().Time)</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

This will work even if `.Numbers` is null, or `.First()` is null, or the entire `Model` is null.

You generally do not need to handle nulls when passing expression trees to the ASP.NET MVC helpers.