# Entity Framework Core map related entity only if it's not null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I have these 2 classes, Process and Task. Task is a related entity and is optional. I want to be able to map Task properties on select only if this is not null. How do i handle it?

```
public class Process
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public int? TaskId {get;set;}
    public Task Task {get;set;}
}

public class Task
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

on my razor page

```
public PageViewModel Process {get;set;}
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int Id { get; set;}
public void OnGet()
{
    Process = _context.Processes
                  .Select(p => new PageViewModel
                  {
                      Id = p.Id,
                      Description = p.Description,
                      HasTask = p.TaskId.HasValue,
                      TaskDescription = p.Task.Description // How to handle if task is null here?
                  })
                  .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == Id)

}

public class PageViewModel
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public bool HasTask {get;set;}
    public string TaskDescription {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p.Task == null ? "" :  p.Task.Description`

Answer (score 2):

```cs
TaskDescription = p.Task?.Description
```

The code above will set TaskDescription to null if Task is null.

Comment: but won't this throw a null reference exception if Task is not initialized because doesn't exist and is trying to access null memory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352072/what-does-question-mark-and-dot-operator-mean-in-c-sharp-6-0 this link provides a further detailed explanation on what the question mark operator does. Is this a solution for you?

Comment: I see i think i understand now. I know about terniary operator but i haven't used it like this before. Thanks for explaining

Comment: Also just to add up that this does not work on the linq select. Have to do like @Indunil Withana said. It says cannot be used in an expression tree lambda

Comment: There are indeed some expressions you can't use in a LINQ query against your context. I didn't consider that. You could also first retrieve your record from the database and then cast it to your PageViewModel. For further reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681362/an-expression-tree-lambda-may-not-contain-a-null-propagating-operator

Comment: That's not correct. It will return null, not an empty string

Comment: Indeed. After testing it I see now that the question mark operator will return a null value instead of an empty string. I will edit my answer. Thank you for pointing it out @overcomer