# C# lambda null conditional

Tags: c#, linq, null

I have following DTO:

```
public class DTO_UserWithCreds
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Ava1 { get; set; }
    public UserType Type { get; set; }
    public string Uid { get; set; }

    public DateTime? BanDateTime { get; set; }
    
    };
```

And I get users from database as following:

```
  var users = from vkuser in _context.VkUsers
                join contextUser in _context.Users on vkuser.Uid equals contextUser.Uid
                join userClaim in _context.UserClaims on contextUser.Id equals userClaim.UserId
                let userBanOffset = contextUser.LockoutEnd
                let userBan = userBanOffset.HasValue ? userBanOffset.Value.Date : null
                select new DTO_UserWithCreds
                { 
                    Name = vkuser.Name,
                    Surname = vkuser.Surname,
                    Ava1 = vkuser.Ava1,
                    Uid = vkuser.Uid,
                    Type =  DTO_UserWithCreds.FromString(userClaim.ClaimValue),
                    BanDateTime = userBan
                };
```

I get following error message (I dont really understand it to be honest):
[image: error desc]

If I change request to this:

```
  var users = from vkuser in _context.VkUsers
                join contextUser in _context.Users on vkuser.Uid equals contextUser.Uid
                join userClaim in _context.UserClaims on contextUser.Id equals userClaim.UserId
                let userBanOffset = contextUser.LockoutEnd
               // let userBan = userBanOffset.HasValue ? userBanOffset.Value.Date : null
                select new DTO_UserWithCreds
                { 
                    Name = vkuser.Name,
                    Surname = vkuser.Surname,
                    Ava1 = vkuser.Ava1,
                    Uid = vkuser.Uid,
                    Type =  DTO_UserWithCreds.FromString(userClaim.ClaimValue),
                    BanDateTime = contextUser.LockoutEnd?.DateTime 
                };
```

I will have compile error that lambda inside expression tree cant contain null propagation operator. Is it possible to get this information like I want? Or I have to write second query?

Comment: You might try: `let userBan = userBanOffset.HasValue ? userBanOffset.Value.Date : (DateTime?)null`. I often have this problem with nullable `DateTime` in a tertiary operator. It can't figure out what type the `null` is supposed to be, so you have to give it a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missed a cast:

```
  var users = from vkuser in _context.VkUsers
                join contextUser in _context.Users on vkuser.Uid equals contextUser.Uid
                join userClaim in _context.UserClaims on contextUser.Id equals userClaim.UserId
                let userBanOffset = contextUser.LockoutEnd
                let userBan = userBanOffset.HasValue ? userBanOffset.Value.Date : (DateTime?)null
                select new DTO_UserWithCreds
                { 
                    Name = vkuser.Name,
                    Surname = vkuser.Surname,
                    Ava1 = vkuser.Ava1,
                    Uid = vkuser.Uid,
                    Type =  DTO_UserWithCreds.FromString(userClaim.ClaimValue),
                    BanDateTime = userBan
                };
```

Answer (score 2):

You could cast the `null` to `DateTime?` :

```
let userBan = userBanOffset.HasValue ? userBanOffset.Value.Date : (DateTime?)null
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
let userBan = userBanOffset.HasValue ? userBanOffset.Value.Date : null
```

What type is `userBan`? How is the compiler supposed to figure it out? `userBanOffset.Value.Date` is a `DateTime`, but `null` isn't and can't be a `DateTime` because `DateTime` is a value type and value types cannot be null.

So to solve this problem, you need to *tell* it that `null` is a `Nullable<DateTime>` so it can resolve the ambiguity:

```
let userBan = userBanOffset.HasValue ? userBanOffset.Value.Date : (DateTime?)null
```

You could also do:

```
let userBan = userBanOffset.HasValue ? (DateTime?)userBanOffset.Value.Date : null
```

But personally I always use the former. Depends on which you think is more readable.

Comment: Thank you, I was not able to think of "(DateTime?)null" thing. Also, there is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681362/an-expression-tree-lambda-may-not-contain-a-null-propagating-operator
                    so it might not work at all? I am adding much code so cant test this part right now.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
BanDateTime = contextUser.LockoutEnd?.DateTime
```

to

```
BanDateTime = (contextUser.LockoutEnd == null) ? null : contextUser.LockoutEnd.DateTime
```

Comment: This has the same issue as the first one because conditional operator doesn't know what type should be used for `DateTime` and `null`.  Also the OP has a typo.  It should be `contextuser.LockoutEnd.Date`.