# How can I rewrite that query - Can't write CLR type System.DateTime with handler type IntervalHandler

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

After upgrading from EF 2.1.x  to 3.1.x this query started to throw

`Can't write CLR type System.DateTime with handler type IntervalHandler`

But I'm not really sure how can I "nicely" rewrite this query, so performing math on those dates isn't going to explode

`input is IQueryable`

```
input.OrderBy
(
        x =>
        (x.RegistrationDate == null ? new DateTime(1990,1, 1).Date : x.RegistrationDate.Value.Date)
        -
        (x.InvoiceDate == null ? new DateTime(1990, 1, 1).Date : x.InvoiceDate.Value.Date)
)
```

Both of those `Dates` have type: `timestamp without time zone` in database

`PostgreSQL 8.4.20 64-bit`

`<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.1.4" />`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you use `var bob = new DateTime(1990,1, 1);` then `x =>  ((x.RegistrationDate ?? bob)- (x.InvoiceDate ?? bob)`?

Comment: @mjwills Thank you, it works fine, please write it as an answer so I can accept. PS: It's not possible to use property `.Date` this way? so it will take hours/minutes and so on into consideration while performing query, yup?

Comment: Does `x =>  ((x.RegistrationDate?.Date ?? bob)- (x.InvoiceDate?.Date ?? bob)` work?

Comment: @mjwills I tried it, it doesn't even compile `An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.` But currently provided solution is fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44681421/10522960