# C# anonymous type warning when Nullable Reference Types is enable

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nullable-reference-types

I am using .net 6 with Nullable Reference Type enabled, and when I use an anonymous type to get the results of a LINQ query I get a Warning **Client is not null here.  CS8619:Nullability of reference type in value of type <anonymous type: int ContractId, string Name, string Street> doesn't match type <anonymous type: int ContractId, string Name, string? Street>**

Here is my code:

```
 var contracts = _dbContext.Contracts.Select(
                    c => new
                    {
                        c.ContractId,
                        c.Client.Name,
                        c.Client.Street
                    }
                ).Where(c => c.ContractId == contractId).Take(9).ToList();
```

What is the proper way to make the query and avoid the warning?

Comment: Can you please post the full code and error?

Comment: I don't think this compiles, does it? You're missing a closing parentheses before .Where. Also, your Where filters on a property that wasn't selected.

Comment: Yes sorry let me edit the code, and add the full error.

Comment: It seems that it has to do with the fact that in the model of Client, street can be null, how can I indicate in the query that for the anonymous type generated street can be null?

Comment: Looks like a compiler issue: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/51886. As a workaround you could try to cast `c.Client.Street` to `string?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var contracts = _dbContext.Contracts
             .Include(x => x.Client) // Include clients
             .Where(c => c.ContractId == contractId)
             .Select(c => new
             {
                 c.ContractId,
                 Name = c.Client == null ? null : c.Client.Name, // nullable check and line up namings of properties 
                 Street = c.Client == null ? null : c.Client.Street // nullable
             })
            .Take(9)
            .ToList();
```

it looks `Client` is impossible to be `null` if the `ClientId` is `[Required]`, the only missing is probably the subquery `.Include(x => x.Client)`.

Comment: Thank you Dongdong, I tried to apply your suggestion but I got an error, **An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.**

Comment: @LuisZenteno updated.  this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681362/an-expression-tree-lambda-may-not-contain-a-null-propagating-operator

Answer (score 0):

Casting to `(string?)` can solve the issue, i.e.

```
 var contracts = _dbContext.Contracts.Select(
                    c => new
                    {
                        c.ContractId,
                        c.Client.Name,
                        Street = (string?)c.Client.Street
                    }
                ).Where(c => c.ContractId == contractId).Take(9).ToList();
```